# Upright sans serif greek in math mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts

Consider the following MWE, which typesets some sans serif math that I'm using in a presentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\sansmath
\[
w\Delta z = \operatorname{cov}(w,z) + \operatorname{E}(w\Delta z),
\]
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

I think it would look a lot better if the Delta characters were upright instead of italic. How can I achieve that? (I like the w and z being italic, just not the deltas.)

If the solution involves using a different package than sansmath, or a different font than the one shown, I'm fine with that - I'm just looking for a quick easy way to make sans serif math that looks good.

Although I already mentioned it in both the title and the body of the question, and demonstrated it with an MWE, I apparently have to edit this to point out that I am looking to do this **in a sans serif font**, which is what makes this different from the linked question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get non italic greek symbols with ams packages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219975/how-to-get-non-italic-greek-symbols-with-ams-packages)

Comment: @CarLaTeX no, that question and its answers don't address the sans serif issue.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I don't think that makes it a duplicate, but it does mean you can post an answer. (However, I've tried it with my MWE and it didn't work for me.)

Comment: The `upgreek` package from the answers to that question does work for me, though.

Comment: I'm happy you have found the solution, despite my confusion!

Comment: I posted a similar question with almost the same title yesterday: [Sans serif upright greek in math mode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313934/sans-serif-upright-greek-in-math-mode). Answers work great!

Comment: @thewaywewalk I saw your question but it seemed much more specific (and more advanced) than mine - I'm looking for any old quick and dirty way to do it, and the Helvetica solutions are quite involved.

Comment: If it means an increment, I would definitely use `w\increment z = \cov(w,z) + \E(w\increment z)` (may be `\incr` instead of `\increment`) and then define the macro so that it outputs exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `sansmath` use the `sansmathfonts` package.  It automatically switches the math font to sans serif throughout the whole document (no need for `\sansmath`).  If you want to use a font other than CM, you might run into trouble with upright uppercase greek letters as other fonts might not have them (or not have them in the correct slot).  A possible rectification has been proposed by [[egreg (2016)]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313959/10995).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
w\Delta z = \operatorname{cov}(w,z) + \operatorname{E}(w\Delta z),
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can use a sans serif font with built-in math support, such as `cmbright`.  This might actually be your best bet, as you get correct adjustment and kerning out of the box.  You can find a review of several math font (no limited to sans-serif) in [S. Hartke, “A Survey of Free Math Fonts for TeX and LaTeX”, The PracTeX Journal 01, (2006).](https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
w\Delta z = \operatorname{cov}(w,z) + \operatorname{E}(w\Delta z),
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\sansmath
\[
w\mathrm{\Delta} z = \operatorname{cov}(w,z) + \operatorname{E}(w\mathrm{\Delta} z),
\]
\end{document}
```

Hello. To straighten the symbol in front of it is enough to add the command \mathrm{}.

Answer (score 2):

In `unicode-math`, and some legacy math font packages, you can use `\increment` for the Delta operator.  If you want an actual upright letter Δ, that would be `\symup{\Delta}`, `\upDelta`, or `\mupDelta`.