# Typing greek symbols

Tags: math-mode, greek

How to type theta as shown below?[image]

Hope image is clear

Comment: Are you asking about how to type the character not in italic? [See here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219978/187753).

Answer (score 2):

In `unicode-math`, this is `\muptheta`.  There are also `\mupvartheta`, `\mupTheta`, etc.  This has the advantage of matching your math font, which `upgreek` will not unless you stick to Computer Modern.  `\symup{\theta}` or `\uptheta` also work.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\( \cot^2 \uptheta \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `unicode-math` package switches your documents to Unicode fonts and requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX to compile.  If you need a PDFLaTeX-compatible document, If you are using a font package, see if it has options to select upright or slanted Greek, or if it supports a `\mathrm` Greek alphabet.  `isomath` has a command to select upright Greek math alphabets.  The Euler font, and in particular the `eulerpx`, also provide upright Greek.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `upgreek` package. See example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\begin{document}
cot\textsuperscript{2} \uptheta
\end{document}
```

[image]